# SQL does not upload all data. Only 4035 rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, import

I might not be phrasing this correctly, but here goes. I can't seem to be able to import over 60k rows via SQL Server. For some reason only 4035 row transfers, but not the rest. Does this have something to do with the file it's being imported from being a .csv? Thank you

Comment: ***HOW*** are you importing that data? You'll need to provide ***way more information*** than this for anyone to be able to help ....

Comment: How are you doing the import? Could there be 69571 rows in your csv?

Comment: My apologies for not being descriptive enough. I am importing via the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard and selecting a CSV file as my data source. Also as it seems I do have 69571 rows in my CSV.

Comment: Anything different about the 4,036th row?

Comment: @MartinSmith It's 65536 rows from the end? :)

Comment: There's no difference from the 4036th row. The rows that are being imported are the first 4035 rows.

Comment: Okay the strangest thing just happened. I removed the first 4035 rows and tried importing again and all 65536 rows successfully imported.

Comment: It still seems that there must have been an odd, or hidden, character in the 4035 or 4036th row.

Comment: Install [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org)  Open the csv and select "View"->"Show Symbol"->"Show All Characters".  Scroll to line 4036 and see what's funky about it.

Answer (score 2):

From Wikipedia on [65536](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/65536_(number))(!);

> 65536 is the maximum number of spreadsheet rows supported by Excel 97, Excel 2000, Excel 2002 and Excel 2003 (Excel 2007 and 2010 support 1,048,576 rows (220)). Text files that are larger than 65536 rows cannot be imported to these versions of Excel.

65535 (which with a 0 based row numbering scheme is row 65536) is also the largest number that can be contained in an unsigned 16-bit integer, and 69571 will wrap to 4035 if you truncate it to 16 bits.

It seems the CSV import you're using has a related limitation, since it imports exactly 69571-65536 = 4035 rows from your 69571 row file, and a 65536 row import works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are the first (last?) 4035 rows imported or random rows?

If random rows, it sounds like a violated constraint (not-null, unique key etc..)

You may want to create a staging table without any constraints and try it again, then cleanup the staging table and load the target table from there.

Rgds